# SpriteKit Scale on tap

Tags: swift, button, sprite-kit, touch, multi-touch

im trying to create a "button touch" effect for one of my sprites, it works well but then I tap with 2 or more fingers at the same time, i get really weird results, here is my code:

```
let buttonPressAction = SKAction.scaleBy(0.8, duration: 0)

var button = SKNode()


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    //assign sprite to node

    button = self.childNodeWithName("button") as! SKSpriteNode!

  }

for touch: AnyObject in touches {

    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

    if button.containsPoint(location)  {

        button.runAction(buttonPressAction)

    }
 }

}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    button.runAction(buttonPressAction.reversedAction())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the SK scale action from

```
...scaleBy
```

to

```
...scaleTo
```

to ensure it will always scale to the same size. With scaleBy it will scale it by 0.8, not to 0.8. That most likely causes the weird results on multiple touches because you are scaling by 0.8 for each finger/tap.

I never used reverseAction before so I am not sure if that might cause issues. If it does just reset the button by scaling it back to 1

```
...scaleTo(1, duration: 0)
```

As as side note you can just say

```
for touch in touches
```

instead of

```
for touch: AnyObject in touches
```

Comment: if I tap and hold the sprite, it scalesDown (which is good) but then if keep holding and I tap with other fingers over the screen, it calls the reverse action multiple times, scaling up the sprite size multiple times.                  I tried scaledTo and it works!, the only thing now is that I resized the sprite in the gameScene to when I .scaleTo 1, it resizes to the original size.... thanks for the previous answer!, I appreciate it!

Comment: Could you mark the answer as correct please. I didnt really understand the second half of your comment. I never use reverAction, maybe just try ...scaleTo(1, duration: 0) to reset the button.

Comment: because I resized the sprite for the button in GameScene.sks, whenever the touched ends, I scaled it up (scaleTo1, duration: 0) and that resizes it to the "true" size, the size it was before I resized it in GameScene.sks

Comment: I see. I am not sure how you coded your stuff but your could for now just create property, something like "var buttonSize". Than set it to the current button size after the GameScene scaling is finished. Than once you reset the size you say scaleTo(buttonSize...), and not the original/true size.

Comment: got it!, thanks a lot!, i've been trying to deal with this the whole day...I owe you a beer! ;0)

Comment: My pleasure, happy coding. Have a look at apples game DemoBots, loads of good stuff in there, including a button class.